# WiX appcmd.exe File Version Check Not Working

Tags: wix

WiX is an odd beast.

I have this condition in an installer:

```
<Property Id="APPCMDVERSION">
  <DirectorySearch Id="APPCMDVersion" Path="[SystemFolder]\inetsrv">
    <FileSearch Name="appcmd.exe" MinVersion="7.0" />
  </DirectorySearch>
</Property>
<Condition Message="This module requires the IIS appcmd.exe command line tool in order to enable the module.">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR APPCMDVERSION]]>
</Condition>
```

Which as far as I can tell is a verbatim "copy" of the [example given in the docs](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/check_the_version_number.html).  Yet it doesn't work.

```
<Property Id="USER32VERSION">
    <DirectorySearch Id="SystemFolderDriverVersion" Path="[SystemFolder]">
        <FileSearch Name="user32.dll" MinVersion="6.0.6001.1750"/>
    </DirectorySearch>
</Property>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the \ after [SystemFolder] ...